# Confusion regarding calling a class that has specialized templates

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a "repository" (warehouse, call it what you wish) that uses templates and can store several Abstract Data Types (ADT).

**Rep.h**

```
template <typename TAD>
class Repository {
    public:
        DynamicArray <TAD *> tad;  // made a dynamic array myself, also uses templates

        // since one ADT has one of the following two functions and the other doesn't
        // I decided to not use TAD here

        Person *findByName (string name);
        Activities* findByDate(string date);

        void save (TAD &p);
        //etc
}
```

**Rep.cpp**

```
template <>
void Repository<Person>::save(Person &p) throw (RepositoryException) { 
    @code
}
template <>
void Repository<Activities>::save(Activities& a) throw (RepositoryException) {
    @code
}
//etc
```

Now I have a controller that treats ADT's separately, so I want to create a repository that reflects only the Abstract Data Type "Person"

**How do I call ?** (create an object of type repository having either Person or Activity as a template ... argument ?)

**Like This: ? (below)**

**PersonController.h**

```
Repository<Person> *repository;
```

**ActivityController.h**

```
Repository<Activities> *repository;
```

Comment: You seem to be looking for ordinary template specialisations, or are these not enough for your task? — BTW, why did you make your own dynamic array instead of using `std::vector`, and why do you store pointers rather than values in the array? Both looks rather subotimal.

Comment: @leftaroundabout It's for my homework, I have to make my own dynamic array (I found that very fun). The dynamicArray is more of a list (like lists in python), I'm not storing values since I have Abstract Data (classes) I want to store class elements, not actual values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't link to a template, because the linker can't create specializations -- the compiler needs to do that. You need to put your templates (from Rep.cpp) in your Rep.h file so the compiler can create the specializations you need.

Comment: but then do I have to repeat it in the .cpp ? having issues

Comment: No, once you include a header file with #include it's the same as if it were typed into your .cpp file.